# Bash remove trailing characters until dash alphanumeric

Tags: bash, awk

My output looks like this:

```
foo-1_2_3_4_5_bar
foo-6_7_8_9_0_1_2_bar
```

How can I remove the trailing characters so I get this output:

```
foo-1
foo-6
```

I tried with:

```
awk 'sub("..........$", "")
```

but that's extremely inconvenient as the string can be of different lengths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/_.*//'
```

test:

```
kent$  echo "foo-1_2_3_4_5_bar
foo-6_7_8_9_0_1_2_bar"|sed 's/_.*//'
foo-1
foo-6
```

add an awk one-liner:

```
awk -F_ '$0=$1'
```

same input, same output:

```
kent$  echo "foo-1_2_3_4_5_bar
foo-6_7_8_9_0_1_2_bar"|awk -F_ '$0=$1'
foo-1
foo-6
```

Comment: Save a character, drop the redundant dollar.

Comment: @Jens you are right, removed one dollar, and added two dollars (an awk one-liner)  ;-).

Comment: Using sed was faster than the other alternatives as I already was using it to add some strings and wasn't passing it as a variable.Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If your string is in `variable` then:

```
echo ${variable%%_*}
```

Additional information on `bash` builtin [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)